# Calling C# from JavaScript with parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using source files found at http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-upload (all credit goes to CSSNinja for the code).  And what I'm having an issue with is I basically need to convert a section of this JavaScript to interface with C#, the problem is i really don't know JavaScript. I need to be able to save the files to specific directories with specific file names based on Session variables.  Current the script calls a simple php, and I don't know how to use PHP to interface with Sessions.  Any help would be awesome.

```
xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.send(file);
```

The question is basically how to convert the above to interface with a class in C#, passing in any/one parameter that is above.

PHP code

```
<?php
$headers = getallheaders();
// create the object and assign property
$file = new stdClass;
$file->name = basename($headers['X-File-Name']);
$file->size = $headers['X-File-Size'];
$file->content = file_get_contents("php://input");

// if everything is ok, save the file somewhere
echo $file->content;
```

?>

Comment: Please be more clear on what this question is about - java, javascript, c# or something else?

Comment: Java or JavaScript?  They are two very different beasts.

Comment: Pretty obviously JavaScript - I went ahead and edited the question. @Mike: Is drag and drop file upload all you want to do? If that's all you need, bringing in something big like GMail is just going to confuse you further.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not related in any way (except that the name of the former is a substring of the latter)

Comment: @Matti actually the code is really simple, and i'm not bringing in all of gmail features, just the drag and drop control presented on my link.  I can get the control to work fine, however, i can't control it to the level i need because of my lack of knowledge of PHP

Comment: @Mike: But you said the problem is your lack of knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: There's nothing PHP-specific about this.  It is merely making an HTTP POST to a URL.  Just change "upload.php" to the URL on your web server that will handle this POST.

Comment: @Matti it's both, my point about the PHP is if I could modify PHP to the level that i needed I could just use PHP in the sourcecode, but i can't.  So if i could pass this in to C# somehow, I could manipulate it there

Comment: @mbeckish just changing the upload.php to an URL does not accomplish this, it also does not allow me to change the file name that is uploaded or the directory on which it's placed

Comment: @Mike - The saving to a file occurs in the PHP.  Your question was what changes do you need to make to the JavaScript to call a web page written in C# instead of PHP.  That's the answer I gave.  Is your question now, "How do I write an ASP.NET page that does the same thing as this PHP snippet?"

Comment: @Mbeckish no, my question is how to i pass in the parameters and the filestream to an C# class

Comment: @Mike - That is a nonsensical question.  I think you are confused about what the Javascript is doing.  It is not directly calling the PHP code to be executed.  It is sending an HTTP POST to a URL on a web server.  When the server receives requests for that URL, it executes the PHP code.  The web browser running the JavaScript cannot directly execute PHP nor C#.  It just sends an HTTP request to a server.

Comment: @mbeckish since it's nonsensical, explain to me how i could save it to a server side directory @"C:\" + Session["userTargetFileDirectory"].ToString()

Comment: @Mike - If you wanted to do this in C#, then you would make an ASP.NET site to handle the HTTP request and save the file to whatever location you want on the server.  I asked you before if your question was "How do I write an ASP.NET page that does the same thing as this PHP snippet?" and you said no, but I believe that is really the question you are getting at.

Comment: @mbeckish okay how do I do it.  Because I dont need help writing an ASP.net page that pulls variables, accepts HTTP Headers or file streams.  But maybe we are just on two different pages here speaking the same languge

Comment: @Mike - I would do what Matti suggests, and create an HTTP handler to process the request.

Answer (score 1):

All right, enough comments...

All that JavaScript is doing is sending you two special HTTP headers and a file stream as the request body, and the PHP is reading that. Nothing more.

`setRequestHeader(name, value)` sets a *normal HTTP header* with the name `name` and the value `value`, while the file content is sent as a *normal request body*. All standard HTTP.

If you know your C# (and presumably ASP.NET), accessing two HTTP headers and reading the request stream should be no problem.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly the problem i don't know how to use the JavaScript information that is provided here to save the file using an C# class.  I know how to save a file in C# i know how to change the name in C#, i know how to pull Session["whatever"] in C# but i have no clue how to push all of that from the JavaScript thats above to those C# controls

Comment: @Mike: I clarified the fact that there's nothing JavaScript or PHP specific about the HTTP request. It's all completely standard HTTP. That clear it up?

Comment: thank you for the help but it doesn't, because that still doesn't explain to me how I could debug this, it doesn't make sense because you're saying it's all the same, great, but it isn't how would i save this to server side C:\location

Comment: @Mike: So are you telling me you're a web developer who doesn't know how to process an HTTP request?

Comment: yes accepting HttpHeaders from a stream, yeah i got that one.  My question is this do I just change the xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
 to xhr.open("POST", "App_Code\dynamicupload.css"); and everything works as intended?

Comment: no i'm telling you i don't know how to make the Java interface with C# class I have written

Comment: @Mike: Using a style sheet to process an HTTP request is a novel idea, but I'd suggest using a standard controller method if you're using MVC (the model binder won't be much use unless you rewrite a lot of it, so it's probably easiest to just read the request by hand), or a generic handler (.ashx file) if you're using web forms.

Comment: it still seems like a bunch of work around to simply pass in a filestream to a class

Comment: @Mike - There is no "Java interface with C# class" going on here.  There isn't even any "JavaScript interface with C# class".  It is just JavaScript making an HTTP POST to a server, and you just need to use ASP.NET to process that HTTP request.

Comment: @Mike: Doing this with MVC 3 for instance takes a total of one class with one method in it (or just one extra method in an existing class), plus about three or four lines of code to grab the data from the request. If that's too much for you, go outside and play some football instead of something.

Comment: @Matti - but why couldn't i just place base.Request.Headers and collect the header information that i need?

Comment: @Mike: Isn't that pretty much what I suggested to you? You can't just throw that into a class in `App_Code` without exposing that code somehow though (controller method, .aspx/.ashx, handler in web.config, hell, you could even do it with an HTTP module)

Comment: @Matti I dont know how to expose the code inside of the Javascript that's present, i see that the line the PHP is exposed but i can't just replace it with what I have because it isn't called

Comment: @Mike: Unfortunately not even .NET has `DoWhatIWant()`. You'll have to resort to getting the two values from `Request.Headers` by hand.